# How can I properly test errors thrown inside setTimeout in Jest?

Tags: javascript, node.js, unit-testing, jestjs

I'm trying to test an edge test case, and this seems to reproduce the behavior of my test:

```
it('should catch async error 2', async () => {
   const foo = async () => {
      await new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, 10));
      await new Promise(() => setTimeout(() => {
         throw new Error('Test');
      }, 10));
   }

   await expect(foo()).rejects.toThrow();
});
```

The test fails, but it should pass according to the condition. How can I properly catch and evaluate this error without modifying the function `foo`?

Comment: The `setTimeout` callback in which the error is thrown is not connected to the outer Promise chain, so the error is not visible to the Promise returned by `foo`. Without modifying `foo` (or doing a *really bad* X/Y hack), it's impossible

Comment: I have tried to reproduce the error I am getting, but this the only way I can achieve the same situation. The original code uses Sequalize and other third party libs that I cannot modify; my own code does not use `setTimeout` at all. Are you saying that I cannot test my code at all?

Comment: If the original code does not properly expose asynchronous errors to its callers, it's effectively broken (and yes, if that's the case, there's no good way to test it)

Comment: Have you tried stubbing some of those third party library functions?

Comment: I'm relying on specific behaviors with data manipulation, and I'm afraid that mocking a third lib will simply not cut it. Besides, I have no idea why I need a `setTimeout` to reproduce the error because there is no `setTimeout` anywhere as far as I can see. This is mind bugging.

Comment: It worked when I reversed execution of the two Promises. But I'm out of the game: the implementation couldn't change. LOL Good challenge.